# C# Excel interop merge cells in fast way

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I want to merge cells and to do it multiple times...
The reason I'm using this merge its because I want more the one table.
and a different number of columns for each table and different size of a column on the another...
The number and the places of the merges are unknown

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp111
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = @"C:\Users\hed-b\source\repos\TESTUserFormFromExcel\ConsoleApp111\bin\Debug\TEST.xltm";

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            {
                DisplayAlerts = false,
                Visible = false,
                ScreenUpdating = false,
            };

            Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(x);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
            if (ws == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worksheet could not be created. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
                return;
            }
            Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                ws.get_Range("A"+i, "B"+i).Merge();

            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                ws.get_Range("C" + i, "D" + i).Merge();
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                ws.get_Range("E" + i, "H" + i).Merge();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            ws.get_Range("A" + 2, "H" + 10).Value2 = new string[10, 5]{
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
                { "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
            };

            ws.get_Range("A" + 11, "H" + 15).Value2 = new string[5, 8]{
                { "bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb"},
                { "bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb"},
                { "bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb"},
                { "bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb"},
                { "bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb","bbbbb"}
            };

            Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            xlApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
            xlApp.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I just looking for better way to do it faster

All these example program merges take about 1724 ms. in my actual program I have much more merges and take more than 5000 ms. 
This merges its what take the most of the time...

Comment: Excel interop is famous for being slow though. As your sheets go larger, it is normal for it to take minutes to finish the job. Some recommendation: Write it as sub or function in VBA and call it from C# via interop, use another Excel library like EPPlus/ExcelLibrary to do the writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll probably perform better if you execute the merge at once and let Excel handle the multiple ranges you need to merge.

I.e. define a range object which holds the multiple areas and call the `Merge` on it. It won't merge everything into one big fat cell, but will merge the multiple areas as defined:

```
var ranges = String.Empty();

for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
{
    ranges += $"A{i}:B{i},C{i}:D{i},E{i}:H{i},";
}

ws.get_Range(ranges.TrimEnd(',')).Merge();
```

Comment: Thanks that make the work.
I found something shorter 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463453/copying-of-specific-range-of-excel-cells-from-one-worksheet-to-another-worksheet

to copy the first row to the another

Comment: Great! Glad you made it. But if the answer is helpful, don't forget to accept it.