# Trying to open a second workbook returns null

Tags: c#, excel

I am unable to open a second workbook using Excel interop and cannot figure out why. I have looked at multiple tutorials/help threads/etc. including [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32987976/2375551) and it seems like my logic should work. Here is a test routine that simply tries to open two workbooks, access sheets in each workbook, and then close the workbooks and quit excel:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


    private static void TestOpen(string fromWorkbook, string toWorkbook, string fromSheet, string toSheet){
      Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
      Excel.Workbook srcworkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(fromWorkbook);
      Excel.Workbook destworkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(toWorkbook);
      Excel.Worksheet srcworkSheet = srcworkBook.Worksheets[fromSheet];
      Excel.Worksheet destworkSheet = destworkBook.Worksheets[toSheet];
      destworkBook.Close();
      srcworkBook.Close();
      excelApplication.Quit();
    }
```

The program fails because the second workbook `destworkBook` is `null`, i.e. the `open` method does not succeed in creating a workbook object. It's also **not** an issue with the file itself; if I change the order and open `destworkBook` first, then `srcworkBook` becomes `null` instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried destworkBook.Activate(); ?

Comment: No hidden Excel processes in Task Manager?

Comment: What version Excel are you using? If you create a second Excel application and try opening the second file with it, does it work?

Comment: @CynicalSection using two `Excel.Application`s works, but this breaks the next step of the program which would be to copy values from a sheet in the first workbook to a sheet in the second workbook. I am using Office 365 Excel (32-bit) build 9126.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaargh this turned out to be really stupid. The problem I was hitting is that I was trying to open two workbooks in different folders *but with the same name*. If you try to do this manually Excel will give you an error saying it can't simultaneously open two workbooks with the same name, but in C# you get a `null` value instead of an exception. Once I renamed the second workbook to have a slightly different name I was able to open both workbooks in the same Excel application object.